# vb.net how to use space in sendkeys

Tags: vb.net

I was searching the internet for hours to find out how to use space in sendkeys command im trying to make an application that can click the key for you every couple of seconds you just need to type what's the key But I can't use sendkeys("{Space}") can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to make it complicated when it's dead simple?  There's nothing in the documentation for `SendKeys.Send` that suggests that a space is a special character so why would you think that you do anything other than use a space character?  I just executed this code and it did exactly what you'd expect:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.TextBox1.Select()
        SendKeys.Send("A B")
        SendKeys.Send(" ")
        SendKeys.Send("C")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I wanted it to actually click the button just like when you click it on your keyboard but after more searching I figured out that you can't use space button with code just like you can ("{Enter}") or ("{Backspace}")

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple...

```
 SendKeys(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers quoted [official reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) (see **Remarks**), so here it goes:

> To send a space, send the string " ".

Answer (score 0):

other way to sendkey:

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Public Sub Foo() 
    keybd_event(Keys.Space, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```